# Importing to 'users' table but also imports to pivot tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, maatwebsite-excel

I am able to import for 'users' table but I also need to import to pivot tables. Here's my code from my UsersController for importing to 'users' table, but is it possible to supply data to pivot tables like "user_company", "user_department" by importing? Can you show me a sample of importing to pivot tables? Anyways this is my code in importing.

```
  if( Input::file('file_import') ) {
        $path = Input::file('file_import')->getRealPath();
        $inserts = [];
        Excel::load($path,function($reader) use (&$inserts)
        {
            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row){
                $inserts[] = ['email' => $row['email'], 'username' => $row
                ['username'], 'password' => $row['password'], 'first_name' => $row['first_name'],'middle_name' => $row['middle_name'], 'last_name' => $row['last_name'], 'gender' => $row['gender'],
                'civil_status' => $row['civil_status'], 'spouse' => $row['spouse'], 'religion' => $row['religion'],'emergency_no' => $row['emergency_no'],'previous_work' => $row['previous_work'],
                'remarks' => $row['remarks'],'course' => $row['course'],'biometrics' => $row['biometrics'],'immediate_head' => $row['immediate_head'],'designation' => $row['designation'],'level' => $row['level'],
                'emp_status' => $row['emp_status'],'dependents' => $row['dependents'],'date_hired' => $row['date_hired'],'regularization_date' => $row['regularization_date'],'remmitance_date' => $row['remmitance_date'],
                'tin' => $row['tin'],'philhealth' => $row['philhealth'],'pagibig' => $row['pagibig'],'sss' => $row['sss'],'umid' => $row['umid'],'phone' => $row['phone'],'avatar' => $row['avatar'],
                'address' => $row['address'],'country_id' => $row['country_id'],'role_id' => $row['role_id'],'birthday' => $row['birthday'],'status' => $row['status']];
            }
        });
    }
  }

    if (!empty($inserts)) {
        DB::table('users')->insert($inserts);
        return back()->with('success','Inserted Record successfully');                  
    }
```

Comment: Will the companies and departments already exist? If so, will you be passing the name or id, and If not, will you have the information in the import to create them? Are there any extra columns on the pivot table that you'll need to populate? If so, will you have the information in the import?

Comment: Yes departments and companies exist. For example the user_companies pivot table has id, user_id, company_id. I need to populate the user_companies. The user_id is the last inserted ids to the users table from the imported data. The company_id is default "1". Is it possible to insert like that in the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way for this case, using Laravel [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships), but when using Laravel Database Query Builder you should get the last inserted id and to use it in next insert in "user_company", "user_department".

```
$userinsert = DB::table('users')->insert($inserts);

$insertedId = $userinsert->id;

$insertsusercompany = [
'user_id' => $insertedId,
'value1' => 'somedata1',
'value2' => 'somedata2'
]

$usercompany = DB::table('user_company')->insert($insertsusercompany);
```

... and the same for others tables, but you should use Eloquent Relationships, because it is much more easier.